# 'Waiting for build to finish' nunca termina

Tags: android, android-studio, xml, gradle, build.gradle

Al principio demoraba mucho y pensé que había sido por conectar mi cuenta de google al Android Studio. Luego desconecté mi cuenta y desde entonces no carga los archivos XML en la pestaña de 'design' o 'split'.

Busqué una solución que decía que había que habilitar la opción en 'settings' que decía 'Offline work' pero no funcionó. Volví a conectar mi cuenta y tampoco funcionó

¿Qué puedo hacer para solucionar mi problema?

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Saludos y gracias de antemano.

Answer (score 0):

Si funcionaba anteriormente, te sugiero primero activar el botòn "Offline mode" (despùes lo desactivas),

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

y realiza "Sync Project with Gradle Files" (elefantito):

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Hola, gracias por contestar. Eso tampoco me funcionó.

Answer (score 0):

Tuve que ir a la barra de menú -> Build -> Clean Project y luego de eso nuevamente ir a la barra de menú -> Build -> Rebuild Project. Y finalmente se arregló mi problema.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]